# Joomla 3.2 mod_login redirect after login not resolving item translated with falang

Tags: redirect, joomla, authentication

I have a login module which redirects to selected menu item after successful login.
Menu item is translated with falang. Login module also, having the same menu item selected.

When in primary laguage everything works as expected.
When in secondary language (falang translation) - login redirects to homepage in primary language.

I have tried setting the same alias for translation, leaving the menu item untranslated - still the same happens.

Login form has a proper redirect url, when echoed it's index.php?Itemid=168, which is the correct menu item id. 
When I try accessing it directly it shows the appropriate page but using primary language, regardless of currently used language.
When I add &lang=xx at the end, it shows the page using secondary language. 
When tried generating redirect url for login form this way - again redirects to home page in primary language.

Any idea?

Joomla 3.2.0
Falang 1.3.1
Search Engine Friendly urls turned on, no url rewriting or anything other than this used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to plugin manager --> System - Language Filter and then disable "Automatic Language Change".